# CWE vs CVE in terms of their usage

Tags: security, terminology

What is difference between CWE (Common Weakness Enumeration) and CVE (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures)? What is difference in terms of their usage?

Answer (score 15):

CVE: vulnerabilities in particular software packages. eg CVE-2013-3527: SQL injection in Vanilla Forums

CWE: classes of weaknesses that can lead to a vulnerability. eg CWE-89: SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

A CVE (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposure) is generally composed by :

- An ID (eg : CVE-2020-1403) ;
- A description of the vulnerability ;
- A CVSS score (I will talk about it after) ;
- A CWE (the kind / family of vulnerability) ;
- A list of CPE (The impacted products by the CVE) ;

With a CVE we can know the basic informations about a vulnerability, we can also evaluate the criticity with the CVSS score. The CVSS score are calculated with some vectors and the score between 0 and 10 give the criticity. There is a temporal score for CVSS. This score gives a criticality as a function of time. For exemple if today there ain't patch for a vulnerability the temporal score will be high. But if tomorrow a patch is provided, the temporal score will decrease.

The CWE is the kind of vulnerability. Theoretically all vulnerability can be qualifieted by a CWE. for exemple if the vulnerability causality is a XSS (cross site scripting) the CWE defining it will be "CWE-79". It's possible to find all these CWE and their description here : https://cwe.mitre.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Software weaknesses are errors that can lead to software vulnerabilities. A software vulnerability, such as those enumerated on the Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) List, is a mistake in software that can be directly used by a hacker to gain access to a system or network.

http://cwe.mitre.org/about/faq.html#A.2